# How to put 1 or 2 in A column according to the value of column B?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For example, if house column is "Own" (it is string), than I want to put 1 to tax_home.
How can I make code for it?

I tried this code but it doesn't work.
Help me

```py
def none(x):
    if df1['house'] = "Own":
        return df1['tax_home'] = 1
    else:
        return 0

df1['tax_home1'] = df1['house'].apply(none)
```

Comment: Can u provide more details?

Comment: Let's change = to == first and look at it.

Comment: even I changed = to == but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would define a function that is not named none for easier to understand that it is actually a function. Then you have to use the argument in the function now called `house`. Then return values based on a proper if statement using `==`.

```py
def set_tax_home(house): 
   if house == "Own": 
      return 1 
   else: 
      return 0

df1['tax_home'] = df1['house'].apply(set_tax_home)
```

Comment: It works but it's definitely not the best way to do it. Any solution using `apply` should be avoided here. Prefer [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73468148/16343464)

Comment: @mozway I agree with you if you want to maximum performance. Though if some more complex logic for choosing the return value is needed apply could probably make it easier to understand than one liners?

Comment: Could be, or not, best practice here would not be to assume that `apply` is needed. Most of the time it isn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
df['tax_home'] = (df['home'] == 'Own').astype(int)
```

This solution uses numpy vectorization to avoid an unnecessary for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'home':['own','own','rental','rental','own']})
```

Then you can:

```
df['tax_home'] = df['home'].apply(lambda row: 1 if row=='own' else 0)
```